# Having issue with .gitignore not ignoring files during push stage

Tags: git, gitignore

I realized after each git commit & push, I am getting a list of .pyc, .exe, .son, txt, xml, .py and every other file that you can imagine.

[image]

Therefore, I created a `.gitignore` file with `*.pyc *.exe`. Yet, I still get the same files on the source control console as you can see. I am not sure why this is happening nor why its not getting ignored.

Comment: The `git push` command sends whole commits. Listing a file in `.gitignore` does not prevent the file from being in commits. (In fact, if some particular file is in some existing commit, it is in that existing commit forever, as no commit can ever be changed.) If you send a commit that has the file, the commit still has the file.

Comment: If you want to make new commits that *don't* have the file, do that: Make sure that the proposed next commit, in Git's index / staging-area, lacks the file. Then make a new commit. This new commit also lacks the file now. (The existing commits that have the file, still have it.)

Comment: Oh i see now I get the reasoning behind it. Thank you so much @torek! :)

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` only has affection on the files added after `.gitignore` file created.
So you should use the command `git rm <file>` on the files you want to ignore and then add back to git.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thank  you so much I never knew that. I actually added the .gitignore files and then discarded those endless automatic commits. Yet on the second push, they came back again. I now I should use rm instead of discard.